# Case statement with multiple possible values ignored

Tags: linux, shell, case-statement

I would like to execute a shell script which is having below code .

```
value=`echo "false"`
case $1 in "26492|26851|27407|26493")
     value=`echo "true"`
     ;;
esac
```

If the first argument is **one** of the values specified, a word *true* will be printed otherwise, *false* will be printed

> 26492|26851|27407|26493

I am not getting the required output.

I have executed like this `sh -x script name 27407`.

Can some one please help in this ?

Comment: What is wrong with `value=false`? What does *command substitution* with `echo` add?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. You can't enclose the option indicators (the pipe symbols, `|`) within the quotation marks, since that makes bash treat that entire string as a single possible value.
2. Your `echo` statement is enclosed in back-ticks, and that's assigned to `value`. So what happens is that instead of getting `true` as the output, you're getting the value of `value` changed.

Try:

```
case $1 in 26492|26851|27407|26493)
     echo "true"
     ;;
esac
```

Comment: @JyothiTulasi: If you find an answer useful, you upvote it; and if an answer solves your problem, you accept it... that's how we thank people here on StackOverflow. And welcome to the site, glad I could help :-)